# Declaring Package Visibility - default android messaging app package name

Tags: android, sms, android-manifest, android-api-30

I have recently noticed that when I upgraded to Androids API of 30 or higher, my linking functionality has stopped working. It appears the reasoning is due to Android implementing the need to [declare package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring).

So now, when I try to open the default sms messaging app on my android device using Linking.canOpenURL, nothing happens.

I am assuming adding this package name to my AndroidManifest.xml file will fix this. Looking at the example code from the android documentation, we see the following.

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
        <package android:name="com.example.services" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

I want to be able to open the default sms messaging app on **ANY** android device. **How can I grab the package name of the default sms app for ANY device and include it in my manifest file?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know what the default messaging app is in order to launch it. All you need it to send this intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Or if you actually want to start a text message to a specific phone#:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:5551234567"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Obviously, replace "5551234567" with the actual phone number

Comment: So I would use this intent rather than the linking.canOpenURL function? Just a tad confused still... I need to open the sms app as well as pass it the phone number to start texting.

Comment: What I posted will just open the default SMS app. If you want to start a new text message, you'll need a different intent. I'm updating my answer...

Comment: Just FYI - I updated the answer again -- the 2nd intent should not have `intent.addCategory()`

Comment: Wont be at my computer until tomorrow but I will update answer ASAP

Comment: Where is the documentation for Intents? I cannot seem to find them

Comment: Not sure what docs you're referring to, but here's some info on common intents: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247805/discussion-between-guts716-and-user496854).